# Cassandra UPDATE primary key value

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I understand that this is not possible using an UPDATE.

What I would like to do instead, is migrate all rows with say PK=0 to new rows where PK=1. Are there any simple ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a relatively simple way, you could always do a quick `COPY` TO/FROM in cqlsh.

Let's say that I have a column family (table) called "emp" for employees.

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.emp (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    fname text,
    lname text,
    role text
)
```

And for the purposes of this example, I have one row in it.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM emp;

 id | fname | lname | role
----+-------+-------+-------------
  1 | Angel |   Pay | IT Engineer
```

If I want to re-create Angel with a new id, I can `COPY` the table's contents `TO` a .csv file:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> COPY stackoverflow.emp TO '/home/aploetz/emp.csv';

1 rows exported in 0.036 seconds.
```

Now, I'll use my favorite editor to change the id of Angel to 2 in emp.csv.  Note, that if you have multiple rows in your file (that don't need to be updated) this is your opportunity to remove them:

```
2,Angel,Pay,IT Engineer
```

I'll save the file, and then `COPY` the updated row back into Cassandra `FROM` the file:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> COPY stackoverflow.emp FROM '/home/aploetz/emp.csv';

1 rows imported in 0.038 seconds.
```

Now Angel has two rows in the "emp" table.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM emp;

 id | fname | lname | role
----+-------+-------+-------------
  1 | Angel |   Pay | IT Engineer
  2 | Angel |   Pay | IT Engineer

(2 rows)
```

For more information, check the [DataStax doc on COPY](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately my ID forms part of a composite primary key and is therefore duplicated (possibly thousands of times). A manual text-editor change won't be possible. Is it possible to stream data out with COPY... alter the key... and stream it back in with one tool?

Comment: Any driver would make that fairly easy. For a one-off I would probably pick the datastax python driver. Simply query for the row(s) you want, change the values and write them back into the table. If you want me to expand on that, say so, and I'll make a full answer below.

Comment: @greenimpala Mildewey is right, it'll probably be easier for you to write a quick Python script to accomplish this.

Comment: What if you have 1000 records?