# how do I change the primary key value in Cassandra

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

Thank you in advance for the help. I have 'status' column as primary key for the table and the status changes from submitted, reviewed, opened and closed. I can't remove the status as a primary key because I need to filter by the status. I am not using due-search or solr, is there any other solutions to my problem if not can someone please tell me how can solve this problem using Solr.

```
create table search_by_datetime_status  
(   
    group_id    text,
    dateofstop  date,
    datetime    timestamp,
    starttime   time,
    status  text,
    createid    text,
    primary key ((group_id),datetime,status,createid)
) 
with clustering order by (datetime desc);
```

Query I need is like show me all the records with `group_id=? and datetime>? and status=?`

Comment: Just to clarify - are you really want to change the status value, not insert the new status? Plus, take into account that you can do range query only on the "last" column of query.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I am trying to update the status but because it's primary key i can't do that. If i insert new status then it's creating new row. I am not trying to do the range query.

Comment: I'm asking - do you need to have the `status` as part of primary key? Do you really need to keep all changes of status, not the latest one?

Comment: Yeah, I need the status as primary key. I don't need to keep all changes of status just the latest one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra UPDATE primary key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022325/cassandra-update-primary-key-value)