# How to Model Table to run query's based on status field which is changing over time

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

Currently we have a table which we query using shipment_id and in future we have a need to query based on status field
Current Table :

```
CREATE TABLE shipment ( 
    shipment_id text,
    tenant_id text,
    actual_arrival_time text,
    actual_dep_time text,
    email_ids set,
    is_deleted boolean,
    modified_by text,
    modified_time timestamp,
    planned_arrival_time text,
    planned_dep_time text,
    route_id text,
    shipment_departure_date text,
    status_code text,
    PRIMARY KEY (shipment_id, tenant_id) 
); 

CREATE INDEX shipment_id_index ON shipment (tenant_id);
```

Current Query's

1) SELECT * FROM shipment where tenant_id=?0 ALLOW FILTERING ;

2) SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE shipment_id=?0 and tenant_id=?1 ;

Pending/Future Query's

list of shipment id's for given status code as of now 
3) SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE tenant_id = 'y' and status_code  = x ?  ;

4) list of shipment id's for given status code for last 1 week

5) list of shipment id's for which got delayed

Above table There could be 10-15 unique tenants
 and will have 1 shipment_id,1 tenant_id 1 row per table 
and status_code will be changing over the time as shipment progresses , from Shipment_started, shipment_progress, shipment_delayed, shipment_delayed_completed and shipment_completed etc 
each shipment in its life time will go through 3-5 statuses , the current table
will be updated only when there is a status change for a given shipment_id  .

I need to create a new table which can address query's something like below

3) list of shipment's for a given tenant which have status_code = 'x' as of now

4) list of shipment's for a given tenant which have status_code = 'x' for last 1 week

5) list of shipment's for which got delayed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cassandra, you model your tables based on your queries, so you may actually create a table for every query you may execute. Also using `ALLOW FILTERING` in your queries is something that should be used for development and testing purposes only and not in your actual prodcution application (check the answer here: [Cassandra CQLEngine Allow Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702419/cassandra-cqlengine-allow-filtering/51706543#51706543)).

So for each of the cases/queries you mentioned I suggest the following:

`1) SELECT * FROM shipment where tenant_id=?0 ALLOW FILTERING;`

this should be addressed by the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE shipment ( 
    tenant_id text,
    shipment_id text,
    actual_arrival_time text,
    actual_dep_time text,
    email_ids set,
    is_deleted boolean,
    modified_by text,
    modified_time timestamp,
    planned_arrival_time text,
    planned_dep_time text,
    route_id text,
    shipment_departure_date text,
    status_code text,
    PRIMARY KEY (tenant_id, shipment_id) 
);
```

here the `tenant_id` is the `partition key` so if you execute your query: `SELECT * FROM shipment where tenant_id='x';`
then you don't need to use `ALLOW FILTERING` any more.

**Update:** I've also added the `shipment_id` as part of the primary key to handle same `cardinality` in case the `tenant_id` is not unique so that the `primary key` be consisted of both `tenant_id` and `shipment_id` to avoid overwriting records with same `tenant_id` As per @Himanshu Ahire's comment.

`2)SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE shipment_id='x' and tenant_id='y';`

this should be addressed by the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE shipment ( 
    shipment_id text,
    tenant_id text,
    actual_arrival_time text,
    actual_dep_time text,
    email_ids set,
    is_deleted boolean,
    modified_by text,
    modified_time timestamp,
    planned_arrival_time text,
    planned_dep_time text,
    route_id text,
    shipment_departure_date text,
    status_code text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((shipment_id, tenant_id)) 
);
```

here the `shipment_id` and `tenant_id` both are used as [composite partition key](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompositePartitionKeyConcept.html)

`3) SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE tenant_id = 'y' and status_code = 'x';`

`4) list of shipment id's for given status code for last 1 week`

`5) list of shipment id's for which got delayed`

these should be addressed by the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE shipment (
    status_code text,
    tenant_id text,
    shipment_id text,
    actual_arrival_time text,
    actual_dep_time text,
    email_ids set,
    is_deleted boolean,
    modified_by text,
    modified_time timestamp,
    planned_arrival_time text,
    planned_dep_time text,
    route_id text,
    shipment_departure_date text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((tenant_id, status_code), actual_arrival_time) 
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (actual_arrival_time DESC);
```

here you should also use both `tenant_id` and `status_code` as `composite partition key` and the `actual_arrival_time` as `clustering column`
so you can easily create queries like:

`3) SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE tenant_id = 'y' and status_code = 'x';`

`4) SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE tenant_id = 'y' and status_code = 'x' and actual_arrival_time >= 'date of last week';`

`5) SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE tenant_id = 'y' and status_code = 'x' and actual_arrival_time > planned_arrival_time;`

just a note for query number 4 you can send the date of last week from your application code or using [cql functions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html)

Comment: Follow up question: for table primarykey (tenant_id) how to maintain same cardinality ? Because shipment_id + tenant_id will create unique row. Which is not the case for single tenant_id key this may lead to overwrite record . Thanks

Comment: In case the `tenant_id` is not unique as you say, we can make a slight modification to the table's `primary key` by making the `shipment_id` as `clustering key`, this will make the primary key be consisted of both `tenant_id` and `shipment_id` so we guarantee that it is unique while keeping the `tenant_id` as `partition key` as intended.

Comment: As OP said 'status_code will be changing over the time as shipment progresses'. You didn't mention about how update will work. PRIMARY KEY ((tenant_id, status_code), actual_arrival_time) works if status_code does not update.

PRIMARY KEY ((shipment_id, tenant_id)) why both key have to used as partition key?What If OP needs query by only shipment_id?

Comment: Concerning your first point about status_code update, well that's a valid case. But as I mentioned in the answer, the table structure supports queries like `select * from shipment where tenant_id='x' and status_code='y'`, so if the at any point we want to do an update query for the status_code, why not just `insert` a new row instead with the same `tenant_id` and a new `status_code` instead of doing an `update` and we can always execute the same query.

Comment: Concerning your second point, the OP didn't mention that he wants to query using `shipment_id` only, but if so then a new table with `shipment_id` as partition key should be created.

Comment: @Mis94 thanks  so its safe to assume primary key cant be updated  (not inserted) ?

Comment: @HimanshuAhire I can't get your question...if you mean "Can we update columns of primary key?" Then the answer is No. As mentioned here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html UPDATE cannot update the values of a row's primary key fields. If you are in a case that you must update the columns of primary key then you can follow the technique mentioned in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022325/cassandra-update-primary-key-value

Comment: Thanks @Mis94  +1 .   I was thinking Simple way would be to just insert new row and delete existing row to change primary key .